# Android emulator device is too big for the screen

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Hello i'm using Android studio version 4.1

I'm having a problem when Open android emulator, the size of the device is too big and the screen is only displaying on the top left corner.(see attached screenshot)

I have already tried:
-changing the device
-changing the system image
-changing the screen size in by editing the device in the AVD manager
-changing the dimensions by editing the device in the AVD manager

Nothing worked, could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if I didn't get the question - you should be able to resize the emulator by dragging the corners of the device. Please see the screen shot where the blue dots are located for example.

[image]

Comment: More luck than brains to catch this corner at the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the Emulator,
2. open Task Manager and find this Emulator's process
3. Right click on it and pick **Open File Location**
4. Once you are at the file location, right click on that file and **Open Properties**
5. go to **Compatibility tab**
6. choose **Change High DPI Setting**
7. **Mark the Checkbox** saying Override high DPI Scaling behavior and **Choose System** from the dropdown

Worked for me! Hope it works.